# Quick Sort program stopped working

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

I was trying to solve the quick sort - 2 challenge on hackerrank. It said that we had to repeatedly call partition till the entire array was sorted. My program works for some test cases but for some it crashes, "Quick Sort - 2.exe has stopped working". I couldn't find the reason as to why it's happening.
The first element of the array/sub-array was to be taken as pivot element each time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void swap(int arr[], int a, int b)
{
    int c = arr[a];
    arr[a] = arr[b];
    arr[b] = c;
}

void qsort(int arr[], int m, int n)    //m - lower limit, n - upper limit
{
    if (n - m == 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    int p = arr[m], i, j, t;           //p - pivot element, t - temporary
    //partition
    for (int i = m+1; i < n; i++)
    {
        j = i;
        if (arr[j] < p)
        {
            t = arr[j];
            while (arr[j] != p)
            {
                arr[j] = arr[j-1];
                j--;
            }
            arr[j] = t;                //pivot is at j and j+1
        }
    }
    //check if sorted
    int f = 1;
    while (arr[f] > arr[f-1])
    {
        if (f == n-1)
        {
            f = -1;
            break;
        }
        f++;
    }
    if (f == -1)
    {
        cout << "Sub Array Sorted\n";
    }
    else
    {
        if (p == arr[m])               //pivot is the smallest in sub array
        {
            qsort(arr, m+1, n);        //sort right sub array
        }
        else
        {
            qsort(arr, m, j+1);        //sort left sub array
            qsort(arr, j+1, n);        //sort right sub array
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    qsort(arr, 0, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you at least have a sample input on which it crashes?

Comment: Please show a case that works and a case that doesn't work.

Comment: That "crash" you're experiencing would be a testimonial for running under a *debugger*, where the point of impact will probably become obvious almost immediately.

Comment: Sample Case: 6 numbers. 4 3 7 1 6 4

Answer (score 0):

You have an index out of range problem.

This will not give you the solution, but it may help you to find the reason why your program fails.

I have modified your program so it uses a `vector` of `int` rather than a raw array of `int`, and when you run this program you get an index out of range exception.

The sequence `4 3 7 1 6 4` that triggers the problem  is hardcoded, so you don't need to type it each time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void swap(vector<int> & arr, int a, int b)
{
  int c = arr[a];
  arr[a] = arr[b];
  arr[b] = c;
}

void qsort(vector<int> & arr, int m, int n)    //m - lower limit, n - upper limit
{
  if (n - m == 1)
  {
    return;
  }

  int p = arr[m], j, t;           //p - pivot element, t - temporary
                                     //partition
  for (int i = m + 1; i < n; i++)
  {
    j = i;
    if (arr[j] < p)
    {
      t = arr[j];
      while (arr[j] != p)
      {
        arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
        j--;
      }
      arr[j] = t;                //pivot is at j and j+1
    }
  }
  //check if sorted
  int f = 1;
  while (arr[f] > arr[f - 1])
  {
    if (f == n - 1)
    {
      f = -1;
      break;
    }
    f++;
  }
  if (f == -1)
  {
    cout << "Sub Array Sorted\n";
  }
  else
  {
    if (p == arr[m])               //pivot is the smallest in sub array
    {
      qsort(arr, m + 1, n);        //sort right sub array
    }
    else
    {
      qsort(arr, m, j + 1);        //sort left sub array
      qsort(arr, j + 1, n);        //sort right sub array
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  vector<int> arr = { 4,3,7,1,6,4 };

  qsort(arr, 0, arr.size());

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
  {
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you made is not quick sort, but some combination of divide-ans-conquer partitioning and insert sort.

Canonical quicksort goes from from lower (p) and upper (q) bounds of array, skipping elements arr[p]m respectively. Then it swaps arr[p] with arr[q], increments/decrements and checks if p>=q. Rinse and repeat until p>=q. Then make calls on sub-partitions. This way p or q holds pivot position and subcalls are obvious.

But you are doing it different way: you insert elements from right side of subarray to left side. Such thing can produce O(N^2) time complexity for one iteration. Consider 1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,... sequence, for example. This can increase worst case complexity over O(N^2).

Out of time complexity... The problem in your function lies in assumption that j holds pivot location in subcalls:

```
qsort(arr, m, j+1);        //sort left sub array
qsort(arr, j+1, n);        //sort right sub array
```

Actually, j is set again and again equal to i in your main for loop. If last element is equal or greater than pivot, you end up with j=n-1, the you call qsort(arr, n, n) and first lines check is passed (sic!), because n-n != 1.

To fix this you should do two things:

1) find pivot location directly after rearrange:

```
for (int i = m; i < n; i++)
    if (p == arr[i])
    {
        j = i;
        break;
    }
```

or initialize it in different variable, update after this line:

```
arr[j] = t;                //pivot is at j and j+1
```

and update recursive calls to use new variable instead of j

2) make a more bulletproof check in the beginning of your function:

```
if (n - m <= 1)
```

the latter will be enough to get some result, but it will be much less effective than your current idea, falling down to probably O(N^3) in worst case.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. I assumed j would hold the index of the pivot element. Although after fixing it the program doesn't crash but I am getting a wrong output for some cases. I'll edit this one asap and post it.